# how to make a label increment by 1 every second

Tags: c#, winforms

for example i would like a label increment by 1 point every second.

For example

the label will equal 1, then after one second it will equal 2, then after one second it will equal 3, after one second it will equal 4 etc.

its like for a survival scoring mechanism. See how long you can last without dying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: You will need System.Windows.Forms.Timer with Interval = 1000

Comment: well i dont even know how to make a timer ? so where can i even start

Comment: timer_1 lbl_increase.text = 0++

Comment: You need to buy a book for beginners and read it. Then buy another book for WinForms. And read it. It can save alot of your time.

Answer (score 1):

From toolbar add a `timer` to your form, set it's `interval` to `1000` (=1s) and set `Enabled` to true, write an `Tick` event handler as below:

```
var num = int.parse(lbl_increase.Text);
lbl_increase.Text = (num+1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this

1) drag a timer to your form.
the timer is under the components tab (see picture)

[image: here is the timer]

2) click your timer (it is not visible on your form, but it is **under** your form) and go to the properties tab

3) change 'enabled' to true and change 'interval' to 1000.

4) go to event tab and create an event for 'Tick'

5) add this code in your method :

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Convert the text from your label to an int
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(yourLabel.Text);

            //increment the int
            i++;

            //set the text to the value of the int
            yourLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        }
```

i hope it helps